Can someone explain this case?
I'm reading Ανάβασις Ξενοφῶντος (slowly). This is where the Greeks are lost at the wrong end of Asia Minor and wondering what to do and Xenophon himself (according to his account at least) gets up and starts telling them all what they need to do. Many of them are worried about crossing a big river (Euphrates, I think). But X says to them:
"πάντες γὰρ ποταμοί, ἢν καὶ πρόσω τῶν πηγῶν ἄποροι ὦσι, προσιοῦσι πρὸς τὰς πηγὰς διαβατοὶ γίγνονται οὐδὲ τὸ γόνυ βρέχοντες."
My puzzlement is with προσιοῦσι. I believe this either comes from

πρόσειμι: I am added to; am present; am adjacent. in which case it is dat. m./n. pl. present active participle.

or

προσίζω: I come and sit near; settle; cleave to. προσιοῦσι: 3pl future active indicative OR dat. m./n. pl. future active participle.

I'm assuming that it's the former... but if so I can't understand why it is dative. Is there a grammar rule or idiom involved here?
The parallel text translation I've got is: "For all rivers, even though they be impassable at a distance from their sources, become passable, without even wetting your knees, as you approach toward the sources." Contextually this makes a lot of sense, but I'm having difficulty squeezing either of the above verbs into "approach". And anyway, obviously the English here switches things around, making the subject "you".

προσιοῦσι is indeed a plural dative of the present participle of πρόσειμι, but it's not πρόσειμι 'to be present' (i.e. πρός + εἰμί 'to be'); that would be προσοῦσι. It's actually from πρόσειμι 'to approach' (πρός + εἶμι 'to go'). Perseus's Morpheus gets this wrong!
There are a few ways you could interpret the dative, but I would just read it as a dative of advantage: "for those [i.e. the people wanting to cross] approaching".

Thanks. I've realised that this dual thing, εἰμί/εἶμι, is a bit of a trap you have to be on the lookout for. But, yes, this is the first time in my experience of using it that Tufts Perseus itself appears to have tripped up.

The dative participle προσιοῦσι is actually a form of προσέρχομαι (to approach) here; πρόσειμι was used in Attic Greek, Xenophon's dialect, as the future of προσέρχομαι.
The manner of the case is what is called the dative of reference or dative of respect ("The dative often depends, not on any particular word, but on the general meaning of the sentence"), which is often used in Greek to specify the circumstances or respect in which something holds true ("Sometimes the meaning is better conveyed with a key word; 'concerning', 'about', 'in regard to', 'with reference to', or 'in respect to'.")
Thus, by this construction, it is indicated from the perspective of those approaching near their sources that the rivers are crossable without difficulty.
For further information see "Dative as a Modifier of the Sentence" from Herbert Weir Smyth's A Greek Grammar for Colleges.

Thanks. My level is so low I can't decide between your explanation and that of Cairnavon. I did however look up έρχομαι at Wiktionary. According to that, the "normal" present participle is ἐρχόμενος and the participle from the future use of εἶμι is ἰών. So maybe you're both saying the same thing! I can't work it out.

No worries. I suppose the fine point is that the dative usage here is of reference.
